# How to print sublists (string) from a list using for-loop in python3?

Tags: python, for-loop, pymatgen

I am trying to use a for-loop to get each sublist from a list like a list below. My for-loop worked but they only give me the last item of the list 11 times. I would like some help, please.

```py
for i in range(len(add_h2o_ver)):
    print(i,end = " ")
    print(add_h2o_ver[i])
```

**Output**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bp9rV.png)

Here is the code I used to print and write to a txt file

```py
for i in range(len(add_h2o_ver)):
    position = i
    for slab in add_h2o_ver:
                slab.to(filename = "POSCAR_{}_{}_{}".format(position, slab.composition,slab.miller_index))
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be down-voted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. Add the information as text.

Comment: "My for-loop worked but they only give me the last item of the list 11 times" How do you know that it is doing this? Are you sure you don't just have 11 copies of the same item in your list?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Of paramount importance is `add_h2o_ver`, without it this question is difficult to answer.